# Google Text To Speech API returns repetitive data for some languages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-text-to-speech

I am using text to speech conversion API for iphone app.

When I pass on a text it responds with the audio data which plays the same text.

This works fine for english language.

But when I try and send a french word in request. It responds with an audio which repeats the same word 3 to 4 times.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the encoding of the data that I sent to the server.

Actually french language had some characters which needed to be encoded. So encoding those strings with UTF8Encoding did the trick.

Hope this helps someone. :)